# Bluetooth Low Energy fuzzing

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any existing SW for fuzzing BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) gadgets from Windows/linux?

I only found the following, but it's not free:
https://www.synopsys.com/software-integrity/security-testing/fuzz-testing/defensics.html?fs=bluetooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the PTS tool from Bluetooth SIG that can test GAP, GATT, SMP, L2CAP and a lot of standard GATT services. You just need a CSR Bluetooth dongle and a Windows computer.

Comment: Looks like it requires expensive PTS USB device

Comment: I could use a standard dongle that had the csr8510a10 chip at least.